# Denotation of Paradox

Tags: meaning

[Oxford Dictionary of English, courtesy of Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=paradox+meaning&sca_esv=439e824fad57d569&rlz=1C1CHBF_en-GBGB973GB973&ei=Grv-ZfeaJoiAhbIPjoOu0Ag&ved=0ahUKEwj3j-yTooqFAxUIQEEAHY6BC4oQ4dUDCBA&uact=5&oq=paradox+meaning&gs_lp=Egxnd3Mtd2l6LXNlcnAiD3BhcmFkb3ggbWVhbmluZzITEAAYgAQYigUYkQIYsQMYRhj5ATIGEAAYBxgeMgYQABgHGB4yBhAAGAcYHjIFEAAYgAQyBhAAGAcYHjIGEAAYBxgeMgUQABiABDIFEAAYgAQyBhAAGAcYHjItEAAYgAQYigUYkQIYsQMYRhj5ARiXBRiMBRjdBBhGGPkBGPQDGPUDGPYD2AEBSKMSUABY9g5wAHgAkAEAmAFQoAH0A6oBATe4AQPIAQD4AQGYAgegAoAFwgINEAAYgAQYigUYQxixA8ICChAAGIAEGIoFGEPCAi0QABiABBiKBRiRAhixAxhGGPkBGJcFGIwFGN0EGEYY-QEY9AMY9QMY9gPYAQGYAwC6BgYIARABGBOSBwM1LjKgB6Ut&sclient=gws-wiz-serp)  defines paradox in three ways, the first two being:

> [1] a seemingly absurd or contradictory statement or proposition which
> when investigated may prove to be well founded or true. "the
> uncertainty principle leads to all sorts of paradoxes, like the
> particles being in two places at once"
>
> [2] a statement or proposition which, despite sound (or apparently
> sound) reasoning from acceptable premises, leads to a conclusion that
> seems logically unacceptable or self-contradictory. "the liar paradox"

These are almost opposite definitions. My English book defined it as the first, but I've always understood it to mean the second. Which is the most common usage?

Comment: Good point! But this will be largely opinion based... or maybe someone can pull out some ngrams... but I would say (1) is the more common usage.

Comment: How paradoxical that 'paradoxical' should be defined paradoxically!

Comment: There is no easy way to look this up in a corpus. One could try to come up with a bunch of obvious collocations clearly identifying either meaning, but that is not trivial, and only an approximation. To be completely sure, there's nothing one can do short of meticulously analysing every single occurrence of the word in the corpus. So while I am curious what kind of answers this produces, I am somewhat worried that we might end up with a handful of "I think X>Y" one-liners. So I am specifically asking people ahead of time to abstain from posting such comments as answers.

Comment: They both refer to an implicit and unexplained contradiction between two viewpoints, both of which seem valid. The first one is more formal, and simply recapitulates the last two lines of the truth table for `P ⊃ Q`, which is what licenses proof by contradiction. The second one is more experiential, and contrasts one's ordinary presuppositions with actual objective observation. Both give a confused feeling, of looping back and forth between two incompatible predictions. Similar to visual tricks like seeing different faces in a drawing; you can't ever see both of them at the same time.

Comment: The definitions, supplied by ODE (a different work from OED), are now listed in what is IMO the default ordering, with the 'concisely stated apparent but _only_ apparent contradiction' listed first as found to be the most common.

Comment: A lot of uses will be in formulaic names like Russell's Paradox and Zeno's paradoxes, which may or may not genuinely be paradoxes of either sort. This points to another problem with the definition: often it's not immediately clear if something is a genuine self-contradiction, if it's logically sound, or if there is some other mistake elsewhere. Hence identifying what sort of paradox you have is a matter for a philosopher and certainly not something for a computational linguist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see the definitions as contradictory. Both cases illustrate the central concept of ***paradox***, which is extreme disjunct between ***A***:common sense/received opinion and ***B***:logic/reasoning.

You could say a paradox is like a *fight*, or a *sporting contest*. The only real difference between OP's two definitions is that if we (the "spectators") support *A (common sense)*, then definition #1 applies.
If we support *B (logic)*, it's definition #2.

---

It's not that different to the underlying principle of Swift's [A Modest Proposal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Modest_Proposal) (that the poor Irish could solve their economic woes by selling their children as food to the rich English). In both cases, two incompatible perspectives/methodologies are being applied, giving contradictory conclusions.

Comment: Indeed. It's easy to spot something that looks like a paradox, but philosophers spend years trying to figure out if something is self-contradictory or is a completely logical affront to common sense. So the term can't be too precise.

Answer (score 0):

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/paradox) brings out the obvious contradiction manifest by two of the varied senses of paradox:

> **paradox** ...
>
> - 2a: a statement that is seemingly contradictory or opposed to common sense and yet is perhaps true
> - 2b: a self-contradictory statement that at first seems true ...

So **[2a]**: statement seems at first glance to contain a contradiction, but on sounder analysis may be ([Britannica](https://www.britannica.com/dictionary/paradox) also allows **is**) true.

**[2b]**: statement seems at first glance to be true, but on sounder analysis is found to contain a contradiction and so cannot be true.

- OED and M-W list polysemes historically, and so cannot be used to determine most commonly used senses.
- ODE courtesy of Google now (at least) lists sense 2a before an adjusted sense 2b.
- [Britannica Dictionary](https://www.britannica.com/dictionary/paradox) lists sense 2a (I'll stick with M-W's labelling) first, and omits 2b.
- [OLD](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/paradox) lists sense 2a second (after 'a person, thing or situation that has two 'opposite' [my scare quotes] features and therefore seems strange'), and omits 2b.
- [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/paradox) seems to conflate these two senses.
- [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/paradox) is likewise less clear than M-W, but only mentions *seemingly contradictory ... that may or may not be true* as in [2a].
- [Longman](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/paradox) again stresses 'seems impossible' (in its second-listed sense); sense 2b is not given.
- [AHD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/paradox) clearly lists 2a first, and 2b (or an approximation) third (numerals Romanised):
- - [i] A statement that seems to contradict itself but may nonetheless be true ...

...

- - [iii] A statement that is self-contradictory or logically untenable, though based on a valid deduction from acceptable premises.
- [R H K Webster's](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/paradox) lists sense [2a] first; second it lists a bald 'a self-contradictory and false proposition'. *A contradiction in terms*.

Though the word *is* used with various senses, some obviously incompatible, the evidence is that the default sense is

- a statement that is seemingly contradictory or opposed to common sense and yet is perhaps true **or**
- a statement that is seemingly contradictory or opposed to common sense and yet is true.

Even now there is imprecision.